# SQL Query in C# application

Tags: c#, sql, database, ado.net

I need to create the following query

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[soft] (
[img_pk] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL ,
[name] [varchar] (50) NULL ,
[img_data] [image] NULL ,
[img_contenttype] [varchar] (50) NULL, 
[file_data] [image] NULL ,
[file_contenttype] [varchar] (50) NULL 
) 

ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[soft] WITH NOCHECK ADD 
CONSTRAINT [PK_image] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
[img_pk]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

No problem with the first part, it's solved like

```
string query1 = "CREATE TABLE soft" +
   "(pk int IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL," +
  "name VARCHAR(50) NULL, img_data IMAGE NULL, img_contenttype VARCHAR(50) NULL, file_data IMAGE NULL, file_contenttype VARCHAR(50) NULL)"
```

But no ideas how to work with the next part. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you're asking or what's tripping you up? Incidentally, the `CREATE` statement you have is missing the `ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]` from the original query.

Answer (score 4):

You can combine the table and primary key definitions:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[soft] 
( 
   [img_pk] [int] IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL 
       CONSTRAINT PK_Image PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, 
   [name] [varchar] (50) NULL , 
   [img_data] [image] NULL , 
   [img_contenttype] [varchar] (50) NULL,  
   [file_data] [image] NULL , 
   [file_contenttype] [varchar] (50) NULL  
)  
GO
```

You can dispense with the extra 'ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY] ' if that's your default FileGroup, which it is in many (most?) cases

Also, I have created the PK as Clustered, which is more usual for an auto-inc column.

[Also](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx):

> ntext, text, and image data types will
>   be removed in a future version of
>   Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using
>   these data types in new development
>   work, and plan to modify applications
>   that currently use them. Use
>   `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and
>   `varbinary(max)` instead.

Comment: I second to Mitch's suggestion

Comment: There's definitely no reason why you couldn't create PKs during the CREATE query.

Answer (score 0):

You mean just load the query into a string? You can use the @"" multi-line string syntax:

```
string query2 = @"
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[soft] WITH NOCHECK ADD 
CONSTRAINT [PK_image] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
[img_pk]
) ON [PRIMARY]
";
```

(The 'ON PRIMARY .. GO' is part of the first query, by the way.)

To execute this you'd use something like

```
var command2 = dbConnection.CreateCommand();
command2.CommandText = query2;
command2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

as usual.

Answer (score 0):

Any problems you face when you use single line queries ??

```
string query = "ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY] GO ALTER TABLE [dbo].[soft] WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_image] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ( [img_pk] ) ON [PRIMARY] GO";
```